# ¿Cómo puedo saber los comandos que ha usado un usuario durante una sesión en linux?

Tags: linux

He investigado que mediante el comando **journalctl** se podría obtener esa información. Pero... he almacenado la información que me otorga en un archivo y busque para saber si existía alguna coincidencia con algún comando que había usado recientemente y no he encontrado nada, cabe mencionar que mi distro es arch linux me podrían ayudar porfavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena opción es consultar el history del bash, independientemente de la distro

Dependiendo el que uses será .bash_history, .zsh_history, etc. Otra opción es usar el comando history.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

puedes personalizarte como ese usuario usando

```
sudo su - username
history
```

y esto te debe mostrar los últimos comandos que ejecutó.

Comment: Gracias amigo también me sirvió tu respuesta.